# Make two div class in a row appear closer

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a data card in the left and the search section in the right

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card  border-info mb-3" style="max-width: 12rem; min-height: 200px;">
          .....
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <section class="search-sec">
            <div class="border border-info py-3 px-lg-5">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                     ..............
                  </form>
                </div>
             </div>
         </section>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

The issue is these two this doesnot appear side by side. Is it possible to put them side by side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you limit the width of the left div when you use `style="max-width: 12rem;` along with Bootstrap classes `<div class="col-md-3">` and `<div class="col-md-9">`.

The `<div class="col-md-3">` takes up 3 of 12 columns but the width of the content is limited so you get the gap.

Try taking off the `max-width` declaration and see if that suits your use case.

This will of course make the left div wider. You may want to try `<div class="col-md-2">` and `<div class="col-md-10">`.

EDIT:
Bootstrap does add padding right and left of 15px to elements utilizing the `col-*` system. I added `pr-0` to `col-md-3` and `pl-0` to `col-md-9` to remove that padding which results in no gap between the left and right containers.

View the snippet in "full Page" mode to see the result.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 pr-0">
        <div class="card  border-info mb-3" style="min-height: 200px;">
          .....
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 pl-0">
        <section class="search-sec">
            <div class="border border-info py-3 px-lg-5">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form asp-action="Index" method="get">
                     ..............
                  </form>
                </div>
             </div>
         </section>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: That dis make a huge difference but still I see a little spacing in between.. Is that going to be default?

Comment: Check the browser dev tools. The bootstrap classes may have a default margin in some classes.

Comment: @user4912134 - Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap v4.3.1

Comment: @user4912134 - Check the edit in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton that really help

Answer (score 1):

Your inline style `max-width: 12rem;` is the problem. Removing it works. I think you can use `col-md-2` instead of `col-md-3`

Comment: That dis make a huge difference but still I see a little spacing in between.. Is that going to be default?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove spacing between two div
have you tried this?

`<div class="col-md-2 pr-0"> and <div class="col-md-10 pl-0">.`

Also removed inline css `max-width: 12rem`.

and If you want little spacing so you can use
`pr-1` instead of `pr-0`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Flex box could do the trick, you could make a section, include the two divs into the section and then use :

```
 section{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:center;
}
```